# Css position sticky not work if the parrent div have overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow, sticky

I try to make "position: sticky" work after "overflow: hidden"

For this design I can ONLY use **CSS** and these html tags: (**a, p, i, strong, b, u, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, img, font, br o span**)

- DEMO: espected result (scroll down):
  https://videochatencasa.com/chat/27.html
- REAL result: https://chaturbate.com/bestprofile/
- MY complete code can be found on: https://videochatencasa.com/en/design-11-chaturbate-profile-already-created/

**Please note:**
I cannot use any "script" and any other HTML elements, apart from those specified above.

I am looking for a CSS based solution.

Attention - **I do NOT have access to modify the parent DIV (that have overflow:hidden)**. My code is just wrapped inside this div.

Comment: *I try to make "position: sticky" work after "overflow: hidden"* --> you cannot, you need to replace the oveflow:hidden with visible

Comment: I do NOT have access to modify the parent DIV (that have overflow:hidden)